# How to burn 8.13GB iso into DVD R-DL 8.7GB

Tags: windows-8, dvd, iso-image, burning

My 2TB HDD is full filled with files. I can't delete those. Also I burned some files into dvd's. But, I have lot of software's, PC, XBOX, PS3 Games. Some of software's and Games is in 8.2GB to 8.16GB sizes ISO images. I want to know how can I burn these files into normal blank 8.7GB DVD R DL.

I search in Google also. But, every search results take me to the same main thing about `iHas burner`. I don't know much of this.

I used imgBurner, Nero and PowerISO also. All software saying that my DVD has no spaces to write that image.

When I am searching in google I found something unique solution. It's saying use `imax burner`.

and I follow these videos also.

1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbcVCihJHMQ.
2. http://team-xecuter.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132140.

But not useful.

Can anyone help me on this? Many Many Thanks.

Comment: Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: Just from some searching, seems like an "iHAS Burner" is a specific one made by Lite-On that has a hacked firmware available for it, which I would guess allows burning past 8.7GB.  You'll probably have to buy this specific burner and find/apply the firmware update.  I don't have any further information.

Answer (score 1):

Any burning program will work.  If Windows, CDBurnerXP is free and will burn ISO images.
You can always burn less than the capacity of the DVD, just not more.  Even if the ISO is < 8.7G it will only burn as much as is needed.  You're not required to fill it up.

Comment: Thanks, Yes windows 8.1 Pro. I used Nero, imgBurner and Power ISO etc. But problem is when I going to burn the images. It says no disk spaces to burn.

Comment: Aha, that changes things entirely.  Burn any ISO images you have first, then delete them when you confirm they are successful.  Trying to create DVDs of a collection of random files requires building the DVD image on your HD before burning it to disc, and that's why it needs free space...  ISO do not require that as they are already precompiled and ready to go straight to disc.

Comment: No, You didn't got my meaning. I have bunch of image files. That I created earlier or downloaded earlier. Now, I need to burn this images into DVD's. I tried these(can't burn iso image files) in my friends laptop. It also says source disk has no space.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your configuration.  ISO images should not require any additional space on your computer to burn if they already exist on your computer.  Is this an external HD?

Comment: I know dude. It's saying that DVD has no space.

Comment: You're very unclear... What do the burning apps say your DVD disc size is?  Have you burnt with these particular media before?

Comment: See, I have a iso image file size is 8.13GB. So, tell me how do I burn it into DVD 8.7GB DVD R+DL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14642/discussion-between-yeshan-sachitha-k-perera-and-ekriirke).